# C# Linq eqiuvalent of SQL Count()

Tags: c#, linq

I have a fairly complicated join query that I use with my database.  Upon running it I end up with results that contain an `baseID` and a bunch of other fields.  I then want to take this `baseID` and determine how many times it occurs in a table like this:

```
TableToBeCounted (Many to Many)
{
     baseID,
     childID
}
```

How do I perform a linq query that still uses the query I already have and then JOINs the count() with the baseID?

Something like this in untested linq code:

```
from k in db.Kingdom
join p in db.Phylum on k.KingdomID equals p.KingdomID
where p.PhylumID == "Something"
join c in db.Class on p.PhylumID equals c.PhylumID
select new {c.ClassID, c.Name};
```

I then want to take that code and count how many orders are nested within each class.  I then want to append a column using linq so that my final select looks like this:

```
select new {c.ClassID, c.Name, o.Count()}//Or something like that.
```

The entire example is based upon the [Biological Classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_classification) system.

Update:

Assume for the example that I have multiple tables:

```
Kingdom
|--Phylum
    |--Class
       |--Order
```

Each Phylum has a Phylum ID and a Kingdom ID.  Meaning that all phylum are a subset of a kingdom.  All Orders are subsets of a Class ID.  I want to count how many Orders below to each class.

I hope this is clear now.

Comment: Where did the Order `o` come from in your query?  You haven't mentioned anything about where it comes from or what it looks like.

Comment: The Order o, is just the next hierarchical group below Class.  You can assume there is `from o in db.Order' where order is the childID and Class is the baseID.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is done with a group. For example:

```
from k in db.Kingdom
join p in db.Phylum on k.KingdomID equals p.KingdomID
where p.PhylumID == "Something"
join c in db.Class on p.PhylumID equals c.PhylumID
group c by new { c.ClassID, c.Name } into g
select new { Count = g.Count(), g.Key.ClassID, g.Key.Name };
```

That will basically count how many entries you have for each ClassID/Name pair. However, as Winston says in the comments, you're possibly interested in another table (Order) that you haven't told us about. We can't really give much more information until we know what you're doing here. Do you already have a relationship set up for this in LINQ to SQL? Please tell us about the Order table and how it relates to your other tables.

EDIT: Okay, with the modified question, I suspect we can ignore phylum and kingdom completely, unless I'm missing something. (I also can't see how this relates to a many-to-many mapping...)

I think this would work:

```
from o in db.Order
group o by o.ClassID into g
join c in db.Class on g.Key.ClassID equals c.ClassID
select new { c.ClassID, c.Name, g.Count() };
```

Comment: He wants to count the Orders per class. From what I can see, we can omit Kingdom since it's not used, and include a join on order.ClassId = c.ClassId

Comment: @Winston: Kingdom is used in that it will reject any p entry without a matching Kingdom entry, but other than that, I agree. Will edit.

Comment: in the biological classification system I think all Phylums are guaranteed to be in a Kingdom. If the data is valid, we can probably omit.

Comment: @Winston, Correct.  Every Phylum is by definition a subset of a kingdom.  My update should hopefully clarify this.  I thought I was using a good example but I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Rick: I've edited my answer... although I still don't see how your example relates to a many-to-many relation.